# How to read binary file and convert it to text in Python

Tags: python, decode, binaryfiles

I have a time series from 1946-2020 for the discharges of gauge. The file is binary and if I open it in a text editor, or even in a hex-editor, I see values which do not make sense. I have searched a lot and found some code but I don't see any time series and values.

I can imagine that the time series is looking like that:
These values are also correct and are in the data.

```
t                Q
17.11.1972       8,66
04.02.2020       28,2
```

I copied the beginning part of the file:

@@4.00
à?š™™™™™é?ÍÌÌÌÌÌì?ffffffî?¸…ëQ¸î?\Âõ(\ï?®Gáz®ï?×£p=
×ï?V-²ïï?§èH.ÿï?Sš  ä               ÍÌL=                  ÿÿÍÌL=    _ B      €@
@@                                                               NASIM26760601m³/sffûB°FAˆ¢A        ¥¼x?  §=,ðñ=ÿ9jŒA´¯DA;Âò@¿‡Ø½    =|?0¥‡=?1=ÿ]”:A                             þA ¨ï¿eV4@)¡?    i3|?`d‹=ek=ÿ‘_î@5Ý@¼˜DA
©]?    cÂ{?Œ%¿=+>ÿÚÍ@                             %µ@À@•9AN?    ýô{?h«=×Í­=ÿð½¢@»MAòöî@        ¤¼x?¸~=Xä—=ÿ9jŒA
+BAïÕ@yBÑ¾    ‚Äw?èrÈ=¯k“=ÿ]”:A¼/±@>. @„×9AG€

I copied the last part of the file, because I know there must be the time-discharge of 2020. Maybe it is in the end of the file.

×ï?V-²ïï?+‡ÙÎ÷ï?                      ÍÌL=                  ÿÿÍÌL=    _ B      €@
@@                                      [image]

in the following screenshot you see the data , when I open it in Notepad++.

here is my python code and output

```
with open("time-serie_1946 bis 2020.hqr", "rb") as file:

     data = file.read()

with open("out.txt", "w") as f:
   f.write(" ".join(map(str,data)))
   f.write("\n")
```

the beginning of output:

6 64 64 52 46 48 48 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 224 63 154 153 153 153 153 153 233 63 205 204 204 204 204 204 236 63 102 102 102 102 102 102 238 63 184 30 133 235 81 184 238 63 92 143 194 245 40 92 239 63 174 71 225 122 20 174 239 63 215 163 112 61 10 215 239 63 86 14 45 178 157 239 239 63 30 167 232 72 46 255 239 63 83 78 101 117 98 101 114 101 99 104 110 117 110 103 32 98 105 115 32 50 48 50 48 32 109 105 116 32 117 110 98 101 115 116 228 116 105 103 116 101 110 32 72 81 32 118 111 110 32 49 57 52 54 45 49 57 55 50 32 40 65 110 102 114 97 103 101 32 83 99 104 117 104 109 97 99 104 101 114 44 32 84 82 41 154 7 0 0 228 7 0 0 0 0 0 0

How can I decode it to get the time series?

Comment: We can't know how to decode the file without having some kind of specification for what the bytes mean. Otherwise you'd have to reverse engineer it. You didn't specify where this file is coming from. You actually didn't specify a lot of important things. What format is it in? What's a `.hqr` file? Where are you getting it from? How do you know it contains a time series?

Comment: I thought maybe the experts know if they see the code at the beginig of the file (@@4.00). But it was just my assumption and I wanted to learn about it. otherwise I have also a pdf of the time series, so I know it is a time serie (time-discharge). I thought, there is somebody who looks at two exmaples which I provided, one can  find this part of the code and can decode it. In this way one maybe can tell the specifications for the bytes. So mybe you can provide some hints for reverse engineering. I provided everything that I know.

Comment: You have some German text in your file "Neuberechnung bis 2020 mit unbestätigten HQ von 1946-1972 (Anfrage Schuhmacher, TR". That text even contains a name ("Schuhmacher"). Maybe that gives a hint whom to ask what this file, what was the tool that produced it, and how to read it. Once you know the tool that produces the file you should have a much better chance to figure out the actual format. Given that German text it seems clear that this is not only a time series but also contains some metadata. So just reading numbers from the file probably won't do.